# Regex Stop at the First Occurrence of a Word

Tags: regex, bash, regex-greedy

How would I change my Regex to stop after the first match of the word?

My text is:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 bob123 bob123 0 Nov 10 22:48 /path/for/bob123/dir/to/file.txt
```

There is a variable called `owner`, the first arg from cmd:

```
owner=$1
```

My regex is: `^.*${owner}`

My match ends up being:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 bob123 bob123 0 Nov 10 22:48 /path/for/bob123
```

But I only want it to be: `-rwxr--r-- 1 bob123`.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a question mark: `^.*?${owner}`. This will make the `*` quantifier non-greedy. But use `-P` option: `grep -P` to use Perl-compatible regular expression.

https://regex101.com/r/ThGpcq/1.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a regex here, use string manipulation and concatenation:

```
text='-rwxr--r-- 1 bob123 bob123 0 Nov 10 22:48 /path/for/bob123/dir/to/file.txt'
owner='bob123'
echo "${text%%$owner*}$owner"
# => -rwxr--r-- 1 bob123
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/JeZMP4).

The `${text%%$owner*}` removes as much text as possible from the end of string (due to `%%`) up to and including the `$owner`, and - since the `$owner` text is removed - `"...$owner"` adds `$owner` back.